# ASP NET CORE creacion de la solucion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Mi pregunta es para entender el código cuando se crea un proyecto ASP Net Core. Hay dos clases, Program y Startup (creadas por defecto).

El main llama al siguiente metodo:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

Donde según entiendo envías la otra clase ya existente (Startup).

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        //Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork>(
                (options) => new CibertecUnitOfWork(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CibertecConnection"))
            );

        services.AddTransient<IProductoLogica, ProductoLogica>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Ahora mi pregunta es como es que del otro lado, se puede usar esta clase Startup enviada dado que como verán no tienen un padre en común o interfaz.

Espero puedan ayudarme, no me deja dormir el no saber como se hace eso.

Answer (score 2):

Es por que lo que el método UseStartup es genérico y espera cualquier tipo de clase. es decir puedes enviar una clase vacía y compilara el programa, pero no habrás configurado servicios ni el manejo de los request.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup>(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class;
```

**UPDATE**

El método que llama UseStartUp pertenece a una extensión de IWebHostBuilder y su contenido es el siguiente:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseStartup<TStartup>(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder) where TStartup : class
    {
        return hostBuilder.UseStartup(typeof(TStartup));
    }
```

El cual usando Reflection obtiene el tipo de la clase enviada posteriormente llama a:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder UseStartup(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, Type startupType)
    {
        var startupAssemblyName = startupType.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        return hostBuilder
            .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.ApplicationKey, startupAssemblyName)
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                if (typeof(IStartup).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(startupType.GetTypeInfo()))
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStartup), startupType);
                }
                else
                {
                    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStartup), sp =>
                    {
                        var hostingEnvironment = sp.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
                        return new ConventionBasedStartup(StartupLoader.LoadMethods(sp, startupType, hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName));
                    });
                }
            });
    }
```

Cualquier duda sobre el funcionamiento de ASP puedes revisarla [Acá](https://github.com/aspnet)

Saludos!

Comment: Efectivamente es como dices, mi duda iba por el lado de saber como es que del otro lado de la librería pueden instanciar y llamar a métodos de una clase que no conocen ( puesto que yo les puedo mandar una clase cualquiera). En mi búsqueda desesperada por entender ello , descubrí sobre "Reflection" y que se puede instanciar una clase en tiempo de ejecucion que es lo que seguro hace.

Comment: Efectivamente ocupa reflection desde asp core. actualizare la respuesta para hacerla mas comprensible.